# Pushing an Object to an empty array in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Trying to create a bookmark app in Javascript. I created a bookmark object and an empty array "bookmarks" to store the website name and website url.
However clicking on the submit doesn't populate the bookmark array. It replaces the initial value with the new value in the input form

```js
document.getElementById('subButton').addEventListener('click',getFormInput)

function getFormInput(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    //get input values
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var urlInput = document.getElementById('url').value;

    
//create a bookmark object
var bookmark = {
    name: nameInput,
    url: urlInput
}
// store bookmark in bookmarks array
var bookmarks = [];
bookmarks.push(bookmark);
console.log(bookmarks)
}
```

```css
body{
    background: #EFEFEF
}
.content{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 70px;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));
        fill: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        background: #fff;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

input{
    border-radius: 3px;
}


input[type="text"]{
    color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: #fff;
    width: 50%;
    margin:  auto;
}

#subButton{
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:  auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
}

.blue{
    background-color: #3D78FF;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Website Bookmarker</h1>
        <form id="form1">
            <label for="">Name: </label> 
            <input type="text" name="" id="name" placeholder="Website">
           <br>
            <label for="">Url: </label><input type="text" name="" id="url" placeholder="Website url">
        <button class="blue" id="subButton" type="button">Submit</button>
            
        </form>

        <div id="displayResult">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Find above what I have tried.

Comment: where is your onclick for the submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bookmarks array is scoped into the function so it will be reset at each time

declare it outside the getFormInput function

```
document.getElementById('subButton').addEventListener('click',getFormInput)

var bookmarks = [];

function getFormInput(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    //get input values
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var urlInput = document.getElementById('url').value;


//create a bookmark object
var bookmark = {
    name: nameInput,
    url: urlInput
}
// store bookmark in bookmarks array
bookmarks.push(bookmark);
console.log(bookmarks)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid declaring a irrelevant global VARs so I kinda got carried away

Answer (score 1):

You need move `var bookmarks = []` out of function, inside function it re-init every time you call your function.

```js
var bookmarks = [];

document.getElementById('subButton').addEventListener('click',getFormInput)

function getFormInput(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    //get input values
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var urlInput = document.getElementById('url').value;

    
//create a bookmark object
var bookmark = {
    name: nameInput,
    url: urlInput
}
// store bookmark in bookmarks array

bookmarks.push(bookmark);
console.log(bookmarks)
}
```

```css
body{
    background: #EFEFEF
}
.content{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 70px;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));
        fill: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        background: #fff;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

input{
    border-radius: 3px;
}


input[type="text"]{
    color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: #fff;
    width: 50%;
    margin:  auto;
}

#subButton{
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:  auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
}

.blue{
    background-color: #3D78FF;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <h1>Website Bookmarker</h1>
        <form id="form1">
            <label for="">Name: </label> 
            <input type="text" name="" id="name" placeholder="Website">
           <br>
            <label for="">Url: </label><input type="text" name="" id="url" placeholder="Website url">
        <button class="blue" id="subButton" type="button">Submit</button>
            
        </form>

        <div id="displayResult">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that problem because of how you where you have declared your 
`var bookmarks = [];`
move it outside the the function scope , so that it doesn't reinitialise whenever the function is called

```
document.getElementById('subButton').addEventListener('click',getFormInput)
var bookmarks = [];
function getFormInput(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    //get input values
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var urlInput = document.getElementById('url').value;


//create a bookmark object
var bookmark = {
    name: nameInput,
    url: urlInput
}
// store bookmark in bookmarks array

bookmarks.push(bookmark);
console.log(bookmarks)
}
```